# JupyterLabで問題なく実行されたコードがGoogle Colabで動かない

Tags: python3, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

**やりたいこと**
自身が書いたスクレイピングコードをプログラム経験なしの知り合いに環境構築なしで共有するため、
JupyterLabで書いたコードをGoogle Colabで実行しようとしました。
しかし、どうにもGoogle Colabではエラーが出て動きません。

**実際のコード**
JupyterLabでは全く問題ありませんでした。

```
!pip install selenium
!pip install webdriver_manager
!pip install -U requests-html
!pip install requests
!pip install pandas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import re
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import requests

op = Options()
op.add_argument("--disable-gpu");
op.add_argument("--disable-extensions");
op.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
op.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
op.add_argument("--start-maximized");
op.add_argument("--headless");
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=op)

print('url取得')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://www.mildom.com/ranking'
#browser.get(url)
data = []
print('スクレイピング開始')
def userID():
    try:
        for i in range(1, 98):
            browser.get(url)
            sleep(1.8)
            WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)
            namexpath = f'//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[{i}]/a/div[4]'
            elem_username = browser.find_element_by_xpath(namexpath)
            username = elem_username.text
            #print(username)
            IDxpath = f'//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[{i}]/a'
            elem_userURL = browser.find_element_by_xpath(IDxpath).get_attribute('href')
            ID = elem_userURL[-8:] #ID抽出
            #print(ID) #ID表示

            urlbefore = 'https://www.mildom.com/profile/'
            proURL = urlbefore + ID #profileのURL
            #print(proURL)
            
            #twitter垢取得
            browser.get(proURL)
            sleep(0.7)
            WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)
 
            Turlxpath = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/a'
              #TwitterURL取得
            try:    
                elem_TURL = browser.find_element_by_xpath(Turlxpath)
                TwitterURL = elem_TURL.get_attribute("href")
                #print(TwitterURL)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                TwitterURL = 'null'
                #print(TwitterURL)
            

            details = {}
            detum = details
            detum['配信者'] = username
            detum['mildomURL'] = proURL
            detum['TwitterURL'] = TwitterURL
            
            data.append(detum)
            
            #残り取得数          
            if i % 10 == 0:
                print('現在取得数:' + str(i) + ' ' + '残り:' + str(97-i))
                            
    except:
        pass
        
            
    
    print(data)
    print(len(data))
    print('データリスト化・・・')
    print('csvファイル作成中')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
    csv_name = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
    csv = df.to_csv(csv_name + '.csv')
    csv
    print('Scraping終了')
        
                
userID()

browser.quit()
```

**Google Colabでのエラー内容**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2979c7c78e85> in <module>()
     21 
     22 print('url取得')
---> 23 browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
     24 url = 'https://www.mildom.com/ranking'
     25 #browser.get(url)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/webdriver_manager/utils.py in chrome_version(browser_type)
    153 
    154     if not version:
--> 155         raise ValueError(f'Could not get version for Chrome with this command: {cmd}')
    156     current_version = version.group(0)
    157     return current_version

ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version
```

**試したこと**
まずインストールし忘れているライブラリを確認しました。
また、コードの基本的なエラーがないか、一度確かめなおしました。
エラーメッセージ内にChromeのバージョンが取得できないと書かれているため、
そちらについても確認しましたが、
今回私はChromeDriverManagerを使って自動適したでchromedriverのバージョンを
インストールするようにしているので問題はないのでは？といった具合です。

Google Colabでは実行できないのでしょうか？
もし解決方法があれば教えてください。

**余談**
非エンジニアの方々に、このようなプログラムを共有して、業務を効率化しようと考えているのですが、なるべく開発環境をさせずに共有したいと考えています。
もし、Google ColabのほかにそのようなOS関係なく実行できる実行環境やまたはノウハウや技術を知っていれば教えていただけると幸いです。

**追加質問**
期間が空きましたが、追加で質問失礼します。余談で教えていただいたTwitterURL取得について再度振り返ったところTwitterでのURLの取得方法がいまいちわかりません。ユーザープロフィールに関するURLである、https://cloudac-cf-jp.mildom.com/nonolive/gappserv/user/profileV2?user_id={user_id}&__platform=web　にアクセスしたところ次のように表示されました。
コードを見ると、おそらくここからtwitterのURL情報を取得したようにも見えるのですが、どのようにしてURL情報を取得しているのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スクリプトにも問題があるかもしれませんが、まずは環境の違いによる設定の問題では？ [google ColaboratoryでSeleniumを使う](https://enjoy-a-lot.com/google-colaboratory-selenium/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Colaboratory 環境に Google Chrome がインストールされていない事が原因でしょう。調べてみると、Chromium 用の web driver をインストールして Selenium を利用する方法が一般的な様です。

参考までに、以下では Google Colaboratory 環境に Google Chrome/ChromeDriver をインストールする場合について説明します。

- Google Chrome をインストール

  Google Chrome の APT repository を登録して認証キーを追加します。
- 必要な Python パッケージをインストール
- TCMalloc(Google 独自の C/C++ 用 memory allocator)による memory check を外す

  どうやら Google Chrome は内部で memory leak を起こしているらしく、TCMalloc が有効になっているとエラーチェックで異常終了してしまいます。なので、ChromeDriver をインストールする直前に無効にしておきます。ChromeDriver をインストール後に元に戻します。
- ChromeDriver をインストール

  Google Chrome の実行オプションに `--no-sandbox` を追加します。

```py
# Install Google Chrome stable version
!echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
!wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
!apt update
!apt install google-chrome-stable

# Install Python packages
!pip install selenium
!pip install webdriver_manager
!pip install -U requests-html
!pip install requests
!pip install pandas

# Import packages
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import re
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import requests

# Set up Chrome options
op = Options()
op.add_argument("--disable-gpu");
op.add_argument("--disable-extensions");
op.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
op.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
op.add_argument("--start-maximized");
op.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # without sandbox
op.add_argument("--headless");

# Disable memory allocation checker
import os
if 'LD_PRELOAD' in os.environ:
  ld_preload = os.environ['LD_PRELOAD']
  del os.environ['LD_PRELOAD']

# Install Chrome driver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=op)

# Enable memory allocation checker
if 'ld_preload' in locals():
  os.environ['LD_PRELOAD'] = ld_preload
```

以上を実行後に `url = 'https://www.mildom.com/ranking'` 以降のコードを実行してみたところ、正常終了しました(CSV ファイルが作成されました)。

**追記**

`userID()` 関数を `df`(dataframe) を返す様に変更して、Colaboratory でデータフレームを表示するとスクレイピングした内容を確認しやすくなるかと思います。

```py
def userID():
     :

    print('Scraping終了')
    return df

df = userID()
browser.quit()
```

[image: dataframe]

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事実行されました。メモリ割り当てチェッカーを無効にするといった内容のコードを初めて見ました。このコードは今回のコードではどのような役割があるのでしょうか？@metropolis

Comment: メモリ割り当てチェッカーが有効なままですと `ChromeDriverManager().install()` でコケてしまうのです。スクレイピングを実行している部分ではチェッカーが有効でも問題はないのですが。。。

Comment: 期間が空きましたが、追加質問させてください。編集で追加しました。よろしくお願いします。 @metropolis

Comment: 実際には `{user_id}` の部分に `11263628` などといった番号(ユーザID)が入ります。例えば、https://cloudac-cf-jp.mildom.com/nonolive/gappserv/user/profileV2?user_id=11263628&__platform=web です。

Comment: `url_user_profile.format(user_id=id)` という処理部分がありますが、この `format` メソッドで文字列を置き換えています。`user_id=id` を指定することで `{user_id}` の部分を実際のユーザIDに置換しているわけです。

Comment: なるほど！流れが理解できました。今回のようにquery string を付与しないと表示されないデータというものもあるということでしょうか？ @metropolis

Comment: はい、その通りです。

Comment: たびたびすみません。query stringが付与されていないURLからだとtwitterURLを取得できるというのは分からないと思うのですがどのようにしてわかったのでしょうか？また、必要な情報を探すうえでのコツとかより良い方法などはあるでしょうか？ @metropolis

Comment: @zumo1224  誰でもよいのですが、例えばユーザIDが `10059231` のユーザのプロフィール URL である https://www.mildom.com/profile/10059231 にアクセスすると `https://cloudac-cf-jp.mildom.com/nonolive/gappserv/user/profileV2` への XHR 通信が発生します。これを Web コンソールで見ると、GET パラメータに `user_id` が指定されていて、この他にも10個ほどのパラメータが指定されていますが、試した限りでは `user_id` と `__platform` のみで JSON データが返ってくることが判りました。

Comment: 「必要な情報を探すうえでのコツとかより良い方法」ですが、答えるのは難しいですね。。。今回の件では Mildom 側が非公開ではあっても API を使ってランキングやプロフィールデータを取得しているので上手く行っている状況なのです。他のサービスではアクセストークンが必要だったり、特殊な Cookie を使っていたりなどして、Mildom の様に簡単に必要な情報が入手できるのは(昨今では)珍しいと言えます。将来的に Mildom 側がアクセス制限をかける可能性もあるので、確実性を考えるのであれば最初の Selenium を使う方法が無難かな、とは思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。少しずつ勉強していこうと思います。

Answer (score 1):

> **余談**
> 非エンジニアの方々に、このようなプログラムを共有して、業務を効率化しようと考えているのですが、なるべく開発環境をさせずに共有したいと考えています。もし、Google ColabのほかにそのようなOS関係なく実行できる実行環境やまたはノウハウや技術を知っていれば教えていただけると幸いです。

今回のスクレイピングに関してですが、Selenium を利用しなくても可能です。参考までに解説しておきます。

Mildom にアクセスする際にウェブブラウザで通信状況を確認してみると、ランキングとユーザープロフィールのデータを別の URL から取得しています。

- ランキングデータ
  `https://cloudac-cf-jp.mildom.com/nonolive/gappserv/rank/locationGiftRankV2`
- ユーザプロフィール
  `https://cloudac-cf-jp.mildom.com/nonolive/gappserv/user/profileV2`

これらの URL に対して HTTP GET を行うと(適宜 query string を付加します)、HTTP response として JSON 形式のデータが返ってきます。このデータを加工して CSV ファイルに保存します。

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import requests

# ranking URL
url_rank = (
  'https://cloudac-cf-jp.mildom.com/nonolive/gappserv/rank/locationGiftRankV2' +
  '?term=this&type=hour&rank_type=receive')

# user profile URL
url_user_profile = (
  'https://cloudac-cf-jp.mildom.com/nonolive/gappserv/user/profileV2' +
  '?user_id={user_id}&__platform=web')

# scraping
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(url_rank, headers=headers)
users = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.json()['body']['models'])
users = users[['loginname', 'user_id']]

# twitter URL
twitter_url_prefix = 'https://twitter.com/'
twitter_url = []
for id in users.user_id:
  user_info = (
    requests
      .get(url_user_profile.format(user_id=id), headers=headers)
      .json()['body']['user_info'])
  url = ''
  if 'sns_ids' in user_info and 'twitter' in user_info['sns_ids']:
    url = user_info['sns_ids']['twitter'].strip()
  twitter_url.append((twitter_url_prefix + url) if url else '')

users['TwitterURL'] = twitter_url

# mildom profile URL
users['user_id'] = (
  'https://www.mildom.com/profile/' + users['user_id'].astype(str))

# rename columns
users.rename(
  columns={'loginname': '配信者', 'user_id': 'mildomURL'},
  inplace=True)

# save with CSV
csv_name = dt.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') + '.csv'
users.to_csv(csv_name)
```

[image: user ranking]

##### 追記

> そのwebブラウザの通信状況の確認というのがわかりません。今回もソースコードから確認できたのでしょうか？

こちらでは FireFox の開発者ツールを利用していますが、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> でネットワークタブが開きます。

[image: FireFox network tab]

今回も `XMLHttpRequest(XHR)` を調べていました。上記画像でメニュバーにある `XHR` がグレー化していることが判るかと思います(`XHR` のみを選択)。そして、右側のペインに HTTP response が表示されていますが、中身は JSON データで `Object` が 100 個あるので、これがランキングデータを取得している URL だろうと判断したわけです。HTTP GET の query string は右側ペインのメニューにある `Headers` をクリックすると表示されます。

> また、通信状況を自身で調べられるようになるにはどのようなことを学ぶ必要があるでしょうか？

`HTTP GET/POST`, `HTTP requst/responce`, `XMLHttpRequest(XHR)` 辺りがキーワードになるかと思いますが、この様な可視化ツールを使いながら、理解できないことがあれば調べつつ慣れていくとよろしいかと。

Comment: 実行できました。seleniumでは実行時間が長かったのでここまで短くなったのは非常に喜ばしいです。個人間の話にはなりますが、以前metropolisさんにはツイキャスのajaxについてもお世話になりました。今回も通信状況を調べていただいたわけですが、私は知識不足のためどうにもそのwebブラウザの通信状況の確認というのがわかりません。今回もソースコードから確認できたのでしょうか？また、通信状況を自身で調べられるようになるにはどのようなことを学ぶ必要があるでしょうか？後学のために教えていただけると幸いです。@metropolis

Comment: 非常にためになりました。ありがとうございます。